# Нужно ли делать capturing в данной ситуации при работе с Dispatch

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3

Я новичок в swift

вот сейчас работаю с `Dispatch` и есть ситуация когда мне нужно обратно обратиться в основной поток и я пользуюсь `clouser`. Так вот `clouser` удерживает обьект сильной ссылкой, чтоб правильно обработать такую ситуацию делают `capturing`.

Вопрос вот в чем я сейчас работаю с примером в котором не делают `capturing` выглядит вот так

```
private func fetchData() {
    if let url = imageURL {

        Dispatch.__dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.rawValue), 0).async {
                    let contentData = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        if url == self.imageURL {
                            if let imageData = contentData {
                                self.image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
                            }
                        } else {
                            print("ignored data returned from \(url)")
                        }
                    }

                }
    }
}
```

Пример обьясняет умный разработчик так что я думаю, что он специально пропустил этот `capturing` , но не пойму зачем...

Мне кажется это должно быть написано вот так

```
private func fetchData() {
    if let url = imageURL {

        Dispatch.__dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.rawValue), 0).async {
                    let contentData = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        [weak weakSelf = self] in

                        if url == weakSelf!.imageURL {
                            if let imageData = contentData {
                                weakSelf!.image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
                            }
                        } else {
                            print("ignored data returned from \(url)")
                        }
                    }

                }
```

Так вот теперь не понятно в какой ситуации нужно писать `capturing` , а в какой нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует 2 типа `closures`:

- escaping
- non-escaping

В случае c `non-escaping closures` не нужно беспокоиться по поводу утечек памяти, так как там их не может быть, за нас уже побеспокоились.

А вот в случае с `escaping closures` действительно она может захватить сильную ссылку и получим утечку памяти. Вот здесь уже нам необходимо побеспокоиться и использовать `weak` или `unowned`.

Как определить `escaping` или `non-escaping`? Ну например почитать описание:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как лучше писать это уже у каждого по-своему. К примеру, мой вариант записи в Вашем случае будет:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    if let wSelf = self {
        ...
    }
}
```